# Why do I get an invalid syntax error in python?

Tags: python

So I tried to start learning python and well I am using sololearn which gives out practice on most things you learn (I need to make a gold purity check based on user input)
Here's my code:

```
#your code goes here
if purity >= 75.0% and purity <= 83.3: 
    print("18k Gold")
    elif purity >= 83.3 and purity <= 91.7:
        print("20k Gold")
        elif purity >= 91.7 and purity <= 99.9:
            print("22k Gold")
            else: 
                print("24k Gold")
```

I don't understand what's wrong, here's the error:

````
    if purity >= 75.0% and purity <= 83.3: 
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax```
````

Comment: remove the `%` sign behind `75.0`. Note that you don't indent a else-if or else block. Just keep them on the same line.

Comment: How much time did you spend trying to solve this problem, 30 seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove your `%` sign and format your code correctly:

```
if purity >= 75.0 and purity <= 83.3: 
    print("18k Gold")
elif purity >= 83.3 and purity <= 91.7:
    print("20k Gold")
elif purity >= 91.7 and purity <= 99.9:
    print("22k Gold")
else: 
    print("24k Gold")
```

Answer (score 2):

The inclusion of the percent sign (`%`) is the reason for the syntax error. In python `%` is the modulus operator which expects needs two values to work properly. Remove it.